# Kafka throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have written my own serialiser to publish a java object to a topic. I set the serializer.class property to my custom serialiser.
When running the producer i get following exception. Can someone help me out?

**exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxxx.CustomFileSerializer.<init>(kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.createObject(CoreUtils.scala:222)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.<init>(Producer.scala:62)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.<init>(Producer.scala:26)
    at com.xx.KafkaProducer.generateMessgaes(KafkaProducer.java:50)
    at com.xx.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:60)
```

**My producer**

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("serializer.class", "com.xxxx.CustomFileSerializer");


kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, FileObj> producer = new kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, FileObj>(
                producerConfig);
        String key = "key1";
        KeyedMessage<String, RawFile>   record = new KeyedMessage<String, RawFile>(topic, key, file);
        producer.send(record);
        producer.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using the old producer with a new serializer.  Old serializers took a VerifiableProperties value in their constructor.  Try the new producer or use an implementation of Decoder as your serializer.

Note also that the serializer property names changed with the new producer as did the interfaces that de/serializers implement (Serializer and Deserializer instead of the old Decoder)

Comment: I sorted out like adding a constructor with  VerifiableProperties verifiableProperties  parameters. May i know what is the new APIs I have to use?